# Undefined references to sql-related functions when linking wt

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, static-libraries, wt

The command:

```
g++ -o "webserver" ./webserver.o -lwtdbopostgres -lwtdbo -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_signals
```

The horrendous, horrendous output:

```
./webserver.o: In function `Wt::Dbo::Impl::QueryBase<Wt::Dbo::ptr<pool::db::Settings> >::statements(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int) const':
webserver.cpp (.text._ZNK2Wt3Dbo4Impl9QueryBaseINS0_3ptrIN4pool2db8SettingsEEEE10statementsERKSsSA_SA_ii[Wt::Dbo::Impl::QueryBase<Wt::Dbo::ptr<pool::db::Settings> >::statements(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int) const]+0x1b3): undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::Impl::completeQuerySelectSql(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, std::vector<Wt::Dbo::FieldInfo, std::allocator<Wt::Dbo::FieldInfo> > const&, bool)'
webserver.cpp:(.text._ZNK2Wt3Dbo4Impl9QueryBaseINS0_3ptrIN4pool2db8SettingsEEEE10statementsERKSsSA_SA_ii[Wt::Dbo::Impl::QueryBase<Wt::Dbo::ptr<pool::db::Settings> >::statements(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int) const]+0x25c): undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::Impl::createQueryCountSql(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, bool)'
Many, many more lines...
```

Extracting the error messages a bit:

```
undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::Impl::completeQuerySelectSql
undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::Impl::createQueryCountSql
undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::Impl::createWrappedQueryCountSql
...
```

Why are these not found? It is being linked with `-lwtdbo` and `-lwtdbopostgres`, which is what the project settings came with. This is after I downloaded, compiled, and installed the latest wt versions manually. Previously I had gotten them using `apt-get` and I had a different set of errors, though still undefined-reference-related.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that libwtdbopostgres.so and libwtdbo.so aren't in your library path. Check your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to see if the path those libs are located appears.

Alternatively try using -L to specific the path to your two libraries

ie:

```
g++ -o "webserver" -L/home/libs ./webserver.o -lwtdbopostgres -lwtdbo... etc..
```